# Convert animated gifs to sprite sheets

Tags: command-line, bash, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a shell scripting request. I haven’t spent much time figuring it out myself yet, but I want to try and convert animated gifs into sprite sheets for use in SDL game development. I know how to break an animated gif into a series of images: `convert animation.gif target.png`, but not how to string them together end to end, in a single image file.

Is there a shell command that can help me create a single sprite sheet out of multiple images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you have ImageMagick binaries installed already, so you can use the following command:

```
$ montage your_gif.gif -tile x1 -geometry +0+0 -alpha On -background "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)" -quality 100 sprites.png
```

That should create a file named `sprites.png`, with the gif's frames.

Comment: I''l check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start on a solution I made:
its has some bugs. I want to add a function to create whole directories into sprite sheets.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Convert animated gif to sprite sheet
#pass in animated gif get out png sprite sheet
convert $1 $1.png
convert `ls *.png` +append $1.png.result
rm *.png
mv $1.png.result $1.png
```